# DeferredResult with time consuming processing resulting in exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deferred

I have one class that extends DeferredResults and extends Runnable as shown below

```
public class EventDeferredObject<T> extends DeferredResult<Boolean> implements Runnable {
private Long customerId;

private String email;

@Override
public void run() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();

    EmailMessageDTO emailMessageDTO=new EmailMessageDTO("dineshshe@gmail.com", "Hi There");

//Very long running call
    Boolean result=restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9080/asycn/sendEmail", emailMessageDTO, Boolean.class);

    this.setResult(result);
}

//Constructor and getter and setters
}
```

Now I have controller that return the object of the above class,whenever new request comes to controller we check if that request is present in HashMap(That stores unprocessed request at that instance).If not present then we are creating object of EventDeferredObject class can store that in HashMap and call start() method on it.If this type request is already present then we will return that from HashMap.On completion on request we will delete that request from HashMap.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendVerificationDetails")

public class SendVerificationDetailsController {

private ConcurrentMap<String , EventDeferredObject<Boolean>> requestMap=new  ConcurrentHashMap<String , EventDeferredObject<Boolean>>(); 
@RequestMapping(value="/sendEmail",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public EventDeferredObject<Boolean> sendEmail(@RequestBody EmailDTO emailDTO)
{
    EventDeferredObject<Boolean> eventDeferredObject = null;

    System.out.println("Size:"+requestMap.size());

    if(!requestMap.containsKey(emailDTO.getEmail()))
    {
        eventDeferredObject=new EventDeferredObject<Boolean>(emailDTO.getCustomerId(), emailDTO.getEmail());
        requestMap.put(emailDTO.getEmail(), eventDeferredObject);

        Thread t1=new Thread(eventDeferredObject);
        t1.start();

    }
    else
    {
        eventDeferredObject=requestMap.get(emailDTO.getEmail());

    }
    eventDeferredObject.onCompletion(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(requestMap.containsKey(emailDTO.getEmail()))
            {   
                requestMap.remove(emailDTO.getEmail());
            }
        }
    });

    return eventDeferredObject;
}

}
```

Now as the processing of call in threads run() method takes 50000ms time so this results in exception as:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:310)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1682)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to tackle this situation..if the processing time is around 20000ms code works fine.

Comment: I think for DeferredResult you can provide the timeout when constructing the object. Just see the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html.

Comment: This is timeout value for deferredresult..as per deferredresult documentation spring container will have open connection with client and use another thread(not servlet container thread for execution)..now is there any possiblity that we have large time out value for deferredresult and there is network time...what happens in that case